# using scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh for degenerate states in Bose Hubbard model

Tags: sparse-matrix, eigenvalues, scipy, eigensystem, quantum-mechanics

I am currently writing a code for the Bose-Hubbard model, and I am calculating the ground states and single-particle density matrix for different values of U and J. As U=0, one would see how the energy gap between the first two energy states would close, which happens. However, as I look at the eigenvector of the ground energy -describing my ground state- I can see that it is changing for every run.

I suspect this is happening due to the ground state being degenerate (the gap has closed) but then how would I compute a valid eigenvector? Is there a method correcting the scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh for these cases?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.